# Ecto CastError: value in `join` cannot be cast to type {:in, :string}

Tags: elixir, ecto

I had a list defined like so:

```
flags = ['flag_a', 'flag_b']
```

And a query set up something like this:

```
from(u in User,
     left_join: f in Flags,
     on: f.account_id == u.account_id and f.name in ^@flags
```

Which gave me this error message:

```
(Ecto.Query.CastError) lib/service/users.ex:106: value `['flag_a', 'flag_b']` in `join` cannot be cast to type {:in, :string} in query:

... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use double-quotes for the values:

```
flags = ["flag_a", "flag_b"]
```

So that the values in the list were [strings and not char lists](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/strings#:%7E:text=Elixir%20strings%20are%20enclosed%20with,are%20enclosed%20with%20single%20quotes.&text=322%20is%20the%20Unicode%20codepoint,character%27s%20code%20point%20by%20using%20%3F&text=This%20allows%20you%20to%20use%20the%20notation%20%3F).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this would also work:

```
flags = ~w(flag_a flag_b)   #["flag_a", "flag_b"]
```

or

```
flags = ~w(flag_a flag_b)s  #["flag_a", "flag_b"]
```

and this would be equivalent to your original code:

```
flags = ~w(flag_a flag_b)c  #[~c"flag_a", ~c"flag_b"]
```

I believe I saw somewhere that the use of single quotes to delimit charlists is deprecated and one should use the ~c sigil but I can't seem to find my reference.

Finally, not to split semantic hairs--what you had at first (`flags = ['flag_a', 'flag_b']`) was a *list* of char lists.  `flags=["flag_a", "flag_b"]` isn't a *string*; it's a list of strings.

Comment: yeah -- really the only issue that i wanted to highlight was that i'd accidentally used char lists and not strings like i'd expected (even if i explained it a little clumsily), and that ecto didn't give a great error message for that case.